# Ajax Post Request isn´t working in django

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

I have a problem with django. I have researched so much on other questions but their answers don´t work for me. I need to send a base64 string of an image to my view so that i can store the string instead of the image in my database. So, I want to send data via ajax to my django view. Due to whatever reason, the form gets already submitted by django automatically and i tried to stop it, but then ajax isn´t firing too. I would really appreciate help because it already has cost me so much time.

**add.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="submitdata()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="dish" required id="id_dish" placeholder="Rezeptname">
    <img ><input type="file" name="image" required id="id_image" accept="image/*">
    <div class="image-upload"><img id="img_id" src="#">
    </div><button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
<script>
    function submitdata() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/add",
        data: JSON.stringify({
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName("csrftoken")[0].value,

            "dish": "test",
            "image": dataurl,
            "recipe": document.getElementsByName("recipe")[0].value,
            "caption": document.getElementsByName("caption")[0].value
        }),
        dataType: "json",
    });
}
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def add(response):
  if response.method == "POST":
    form = AddForm(response.POST, response.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        
        print(response.POST)
        # The print statement prints the data from the automatical form 
          submit, not from the ajax submit


        current_user = Client.objects.get(id=response.user.id)
        current_user.post_set.create(poster=response.user.username,
                                    dish=form.cleaned_data.get("dish"),
                                    image=response.POST.get("image"),
                                    caption=form.cleaned_data.get("caption"),
                                    recipe=form.cleaned_data.get("recipe"))
        
        messages.success(response, "You successfully added a post.")
        return redirect("home")

else:
    form = AddForm()

return render(response, "main/add.html", {"form":form})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path("add", views.add, name="add")
]
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):

dish = forms.CharField()
image = forms.FileField()
caption = forms.TextInput()
recipe = forms.TextInput()

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ["dish", "image", "recipe", "caption"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the onsubmit property and want to prevent the form from sending data, make sure the handler returns false.

If the onsubmit handler returns false, the elements of the form are not submitted. If the handler returns any other value or returns nothing, the form is submitted normally.

```
<script>
    function submitdata() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/add",
        data: JSON.stringify({

            "dish": "test",
            "image": dataurl,
            "recipe": document.getElementsByName("recipe")[0].value,
            "caption": document.getElementsByName("caption")[0].value
        }),
        dataType: "json",

        //return false if ajax is successful
        // you can also do something with response data if needed
        success: function(data) {return false;},
        //return false if ajax request returns error
        error: function(data) {return false;},
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Trying this, the form is submitting when I click the button, but again without the ajax post.

Comment: @Moritz_1201: This is because the ajax request is probably returning an error. In a similar fashion you can add error: function(data) {return false;}. This will stop the form form from being submitted in any case. But you need to handle your error.

Comment: I tried to console.log the error, and it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') " (Edit: it had to do with the csrfmiddlewaretoken so now the error isn´t there anymore but it´s still not working)